# How can I pass from matrix to Dic undirected graph rapresentation python in python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Hi all I have a graph represented as a matrix and I would like to transform it into a dictionary that I will show below

```
X050412_1_0012_2_2_000018': array([[ 0.        , 34.47078581,  0.        ,  0.        ],
           [34.47078581,  0.        , 27.21108928, 28.34990025],
           [ 0.        , 27.21108928,  0.        , 21.57154446],
           [ 0.        , 28.34990025, 21.57154446,  0.        ]])
```

I would like to create a dictionary rapresentation of my undirected graph, in which instead putting the number of the distance (34.47 ... so on) I just put if there is a connection between the two now, so for example node 1 is connected only to node 2

```
X050412_1_0012_2_2_000018': {1:2,
2:1,3,4
3:2,4
4:2,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with the following function

```
def from_m_to_dict(L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        Diz_C[i] = []
        #print(Diz_C)
        for i2 in range(len(L[i])):
            if L[i][i2] != 0:
                Diz_C[i].append(i2)

    print(Diz_C)

from_m_to_dict(L)
```